# Powershell -like operator is not commutative

Tags: powershell, commutativity

Consider the following:

```
$var = 'Now is the time'
if ($var -like 'Now*') { 'true' } else { 'false' }
```

Output: **true**

Now swap the two operands for the -like operator:

```
if ('Now*' -like $var) { 'true' } else { 'false' }
```

Output: **false**

The -like operator is not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).  Is this as expected?

I am on Win 7, using PS version 2. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, and to me is seems logical too because you are allowed to use wildcard patterns on the right side. Using wildcard patterns to match wildcard patterns would be odd, don't you think? And not to mention the possible ambiguities that commutativity would introduce to the `-like` operator: `'Hello.*' -like 'Hello?'` - would this return `true` or `false` were `-like` commutative? I bet my PC would crash on that one...

Comment: +1 @davor - right, the case of comparing wildcard against wildcard had not occurred to me.  But if wildcards are to appear on the right hand side, why does the second case above not generate an error?

Comment: Wildcards are escaped characters on the left side.

Comment: @davor - I'm sorry, don't understand what that means.

Comment: `?` when used on the left side will be seen as a simple character: question mark. If `?`is used on the right side, it will be seen as a wildcard and match any character on the left side. `'aa' -like 'a?'` (true - `?` is wildcard). Turn it around and the `?` is seen as a question mark - not wildcard. Same holds for `*`and other wildcards...

Comment: Brilliant, that explains it.  'Now*' on the left hand side is literally the string Now followed by an asterix.  Tried it out - `('Now*' -like 'Now*')` yields true but `('Now*' -like 'NowA')` does not match. Could you please submit an answer (it can simply say "see discussion above') so I can assign you the answer? Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-Like` behaves not commutative - this is expected.

**Some points:**

1. A summary of the discussion above in the comments: Commutativity would introduce ambiguity: `'Hello.*' -like 'Hello?'` - would this return `true` or `false` were `-like` commutative? Therefor wildcard characters are only allowed on the right side. If they appear on the left size, they are considered literals - not wildcards.

If someone else has other valid points: feel free to edit or give a better answer.